# Flutter How to find spesific word of string?

Tags: flutter

I have a TextField and controller. I am trying to find word inside this controller.

This is the text from TextField:

> Hello people, from Mars

I tried this and this code returning how many word the controller has. So, it is 4.

```
    int mLength = controller1.text.split(' ').length;
    debugPrint(mLength.toString());
```

Then I tried the find last word with this code:

```
 debugPrint(controller1.text.split(" ").elementAt(isimLenght - 1));
```

But the problem has begin here. How do I know, how many word written by user? Maybe 4, maybe 10..
If I try to get first word or third word or seventh word, how do I get it?
I tried to use  `for`  and  `for in`  but couldn't handle with these.

Comment: I can't understand where the problem is: if you want the 4th letter, use `.elementAt(3)`, or `.elementAt(9)` for the 10th. You just need to test on the `split` length before trying to access the element to avoid errors (or handle the error if you don't want to test on length).

Comment: Problem is, how do I know how many words written by user? If user wrote "Hello everyone" and If the code was ```.elementAt(9)``` it returns an error.

Comment: You can't, but you can work around the errors. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that you don't know the number of words in advance, but you still need to get some words at precise positions.
You can do it this way:

```
var words = controller1.text.split(' ');
var fourthWord = ''; //assign here a default value, so you have the variable available later
var tenthWord = '';
//and so on, for each word in a precise position you need

if (words.length> 3){
   fourthWord = words[3];
}
if (words.length> 9){
   tenthWord = words[9];
}
//and so on...

//I suppose you need these words for something: in this way you have all of them set by default as empty 
processWords(fourthWord, tenthWord);
```

Another way is by using `try...catch` to get the errors, but the result is pretty much the same. Short example, instead of using `if`:

```
try{
  fourthWord=words[3];
} catch (e) {
  print('Not enough words');
}
```

}

Comment: Oh mate thanks a lot. Finally, appreciate to you.

Answer (score 1):

`controller1.text` is of String type which means all the methods from String class can be used to search a word, replace, find lenght etc.

`controller1.text.split(' ')` returns an array of Strings which means all the operations allowed on arrays or Lists are also by default possible here.

**Search a specific word:**

```
controller1.text.contains('from'); // Returns TRUE/FALSE
controller1.text.indexOf('from'); // Returns the start index
```

**Get the count of words:**

```
List<String> words = controller1.text.split(' ');
debugPrint(words[5]);
```

Comment: It's not helping. I want get how many word written by user and print it one by one them. Because I'll use each word for something.

Comment: you have an array. Loop over that and print... should not be an issue

Comment: Let's think about user has this text '' My computer is old ''. This sentence has 4 word. I did exactly what did you say and try to ```print(words[5])```. It returns an error because we have 4 word. I think we have to think about ```[5]```. It must be variable which it depents how many words written by user but how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of words by:

```
var words = controller1.text.split(' ');
```

Iterating them:

```
for (var word in words) {
  print(word);
}
```

Pick one of them:

```
var picked = words[2];
```

How many words did the user input?

```
var count = words.length;
print('words: $count');
```

If you want to split the string by a space and the input contains no space at all, the result array will contain only 1 element - the whole string.
But we could define a word without using a space separator.
Maybe just an arbitrary string, try this example:

```
  void test() {
    var fullText = 'foobarfoofoobarbar';
    var searchFrom = 0;    
    var keyword = 'foo';
    var index = fullText.indexOf(keyword, searchFrom);  
    //will quit the loop if 'foo' cannot be found anymore  
    while (index != -1) {
      //first word 'foo' starts from index to index+3
      var firstFoo = fullText.substring(index, index + keyword.length);
      print('word $firstFoo: $index ${index + keyword.length}');
      
      //find next word 'foo' from index after the last one:
      searchFrom = index;
      index = fullText.indexOf('foo', searchFrom);
    }
    
  }
```

Didn't test it yet so no guaranteed it's working. But you could get the idea of searching inside a string.

Comment: Okey but If user wrote with 1 word, what will happen? I think an error.

Comment: @TolgaYılmaz Updated the answer. Try using 'indexOf' to find an arbitrary string.

Comment: Sorry mate not helping but big thank you.

Comment: @TolgaYılmaz Then maybe your question is not what you're asking. What the user inputs are dynamic. So you should not hard code to find a specific word from it. What are you implementing? Try to tell us your case, that will help us understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
 var h = "Hello people, from Mars Hello==1 people1==, from1== Mars1==";
  var split = h.split(" ");
  printme(split, 0);
  printme(split, 1);
  printme(split, 2);
  printme(split, 3);
  printme(split, 4);
  printme(split, 5);
  printme(split, 6);
  printme(split, 7);
  printme(split, 8);
  printme(split, 9);
  printme(split, 10);

  printme(split, 11);
  printme(split, 12);
  printme(split, 100);
  printme(split, -1);
}

printme(split, int t) {
  var st = split.length - t.abs() > 0 ? split.elementAt(t.abs()) : "";
  print("$t=============>" + st);
  return st;
}
```

**Output**

```
0=============>Hello
1=============>people,
2=============>from
3=============>Mars
4=============>Hello==1
5=============>people1==,
6=============>from1==
7=============>Mars1==
8=============>
9=============>
10=============>
11=============>
12=============>
100=============>
-1=============>people,
```

**Smaple Code**[dart pad code](https://dartpad.dev/?id=fb98c1e966096188088c352e627253eb)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

TextEditingController   _textcontroller= new TextEditingController(
    text: "Hello people, from Mars Hello==1 people1==, from1== Mars1==");
TextEditingController _textlengthcontroller = new TextEditingController();
var text = "";

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: _textcontroller,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 100,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _textlengthcontroller,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              text,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  var s = printme(_textcontroller.text.split(" "),
                      int.parse(_textlengthcontroller.text));
                  setState(() {
                    text = s;
                  });
                },
                child: Text("Find My word"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  printme(split, int t) {
    var st = split.length - t.abs() > 0
        ? split.elementAt(t.abs())
        : " ===============No WordFound=========";
    print("$t=============>" + st);
    return st;
  }
}
```